# How to get variable names declared in Interface / Class in angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript

is it possible to get all the public variable's name of interface or class?

He is the interface that I am using:

```
export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: object;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}
```

Expected output is: name, position, weight, symbol.

I can define one array which has all variable name, but I am curious to know if we have anything like fetching variable names.

**Update**

Just checked the other possible duplicate link. But the solution suggests to create new instance of class, I don't want to do that. I want to have the variable name of interface without any instantiation.

Comment: How do you think this could work? If you just define a class, without referencing it or create an object you can't access it. It isn't even in your memory.

Comment: Is it possible if we can reference it? I don't want to create instance. There are various alternatives, but I wanted to know if I can do without instantiation.